# Checkbox con JQuery (seleccionar y deseccionar )

Tags: javascript, html

Les traigo una consulta respecto a jQuery y HTML, dispongo de un formulario y en esta tres checkbox lo cual cada uno va tener un comportamiento diferente es decir cuando selecciones el primer checkbox me muestre en  cuando lo deselecciones me oculte dicho div hasta el momento he conseguido lo siguiente:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $("#checkbox1").click(function(){
      if(this.checked == true){
        id = $(this).val();
        $.post("index.php?action=getcolor1", {id:id}, function(data){
          $("#result").html(data);
          $("#checkbox2").attr('checked', false);
          $("#checkbox3").attr('checked', false);
        });

      }else if(this.checked == false){
        $("#result").hide();
      }
    });

     $("#checkbox2").click(function(){
      if(this.checked == true){
        id = $(this).val();
        $.post("index.php?action=getcolor2", {id:id}, function(data){
        $("#result").html(data);
        $("#checkbox1").attr('checked', false);
        $("#checkbox3").attr('checked', false);
      });

      }else if(this.checked == false){
        $("#result").hide();
      }
  });

      $("#checkbox3").click(function(){
      if(this.checked == true){

        id = $(this).val();
      $.post("index.php?action=getcolor3", {id:id}, function(data){
        $("#result").html(data);
        $("#checkbox1").attr('checked', false);
         $("#checkbox2").attr('checked', false);

      });

      }else if(this.checked == false){
        $("#result").hide(); 
    }

  });
});
```

Hasta en este momento puedo llamar cada uno de los elementos de cada checkbox pero al momento de deselecionar no mi quita mi `<div id="#result"></div>`.

Alguien me puede mencionar alguna referencia.

[image: Aqui referencias]

Comment: Hola! Podrías agregar la parte del HTML? Veo en tu función JS que solamente estas ocultando el elemento con id "result" ($("#result").hide();)...

Comment: Creo que no terminas de expresar con claridad lo que quieres. ¿Podrías releer la pregunta, [editarla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/102092/edit) y expresar con más claridad lo que quieres lograr exactamente?.

Answer (score 3):

Ya encontré la solución solo cambie mi `$("#result").hide();` a `$("#result").empty();`  por si a alguien más le sirve.

Comment: es cierto que es funciona, pero, no se aplica la función ocultar o mostrar, ya que el método empty() lo que hace es quitar(eliminar) lo que este dentro del componente html. Solo esa aclaración para no confundir a quien lo desconozca